# Why aren't levels in Agda inferred?

Tags: agda

http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism

In Agda, Level is an explicit value that one can specify, so you need to make sure to quantify over all n if you want a type that works at all levels.

Coq's paper for [universe polymorphism](https://www.irif.fr/~sozeau/research/publications/Universe_Polymorphism_in_Coq.pdf) seems to indicate that n can be inferred, such that one can write a `Set : Set` and still have a consistent language (where it is automatically turned into something of the form `{n m} Set n : Set m`, and constraint of `n < m` is added to the context).

Is there some assumption that Agda makes that makes it impossible for the levels to infer? (Or makes it infeasible to compute for some reason?)

Comment: You may be interested in my blog post about sorts and levels in Agda: https://jesper.sikanda.be/posts/agdas-new-sorts.html